# How can I programmatically access System.Windows.ResourceDictionary?

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, inkcanvas

I am trying to implement Load/Save annotations (complex children, not ink strokes, like an editable text box) of an InkCanvas and when I use XamlReader.Load I get an exception where it is trying to load something into the dictionary that is already there. I believe I need to access the dictionary and either check to see if something is already there or just clear it out.

My question is, how can I access the resource dictionary programmatically or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: In my case, it was Application.Current.Resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All FrameworkElement derived classes include a [Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources.aspx) property you can use to access the resource dictionary for that element.  You can also directly access [Application.Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.resources.aspx) if the resource is defined at the Application level.